# Sending Attachments with XML Message to Websphere MQ queue

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a need to put a XML Message in the MQ queue with the attachments. Is that possible?. Please share your thoughts/relevant documentation.

Comment: Which MQ? WebSphere MQ? ActiveMQ? Zero MQ? MSMQ? Sonic MQ? Fiorano MQ?

Answer (score 1):

You can put any type of message payload to a MQ queue. XML (which is of type Text/String), bytes, etc. MQ does not care about payload type.

You will have to create a byte or text buffer containing your XML with attachments and put the message to a queue.